# Setting parse images to a tableView Cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, parse-platform

I'm trying to save images from Parse to a variable called image stored which I can then set to tableview cells. At the moment I just have the images from parse being saved to a PFImageView. But when I try to set these to Table View Cells I get an error :  Cannot assign value of type 'PFImageView' to type 'UIImage?' .  Really appreciate any help.

Here's my code:

```
import UIKit
import Parse
import Bolts
import ParseUI

class YourEvents: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    var currentuser = PFUser.currentUser()?.username


    //array
    var testArray = [String]()

    var testdecr = [String]()
    var image = UIImage()

     var imagestored = PFImageView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        var query = PFQuery(className:"Companies")
         let pUserName = PFUser.currentUser()?["username"] as? String

        query.whereKey("createdby", equalTo:"\(pUserName)")
        // let runkey = query.orderByAscending("companyname")
        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{
            (objects: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

            if error == nil {
                //do something with the found objects
                if let objects = objects as [PFObject]! {
                    for object in objects {

                        let load = object.objectForKey("companyname") as! String
                        self.testArray .append(load)

                        print(self.testArray)

                        let load2 = object.objectForKey("companydescription") as! String
                        self.testdecr.append(load2)

                        print(self.testdecr)

                         if let userImageFile = object["imagefile"] as? PFFile {
                         userImageFile.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock {
                            (imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                            if error == nil {
                                if let imageData = imageData {
                                     self.image = UIImage(data:imageData)!
                                }
                            }
                        }

                    }


                        }

                }
            } else {
                //log details of failure
                print("Error: \(error!) \(error?.userInfo) ")

            }


        }

        // reload  UIViewController and UITabkeView
        sleep(3)

        do_table_refresh()
    }

    func do_table_refresh () {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),  {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
            return
        })
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }



    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return testArray.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("yourstartups", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! YourStartupsCell
        cell.lbTitle!.text = self.testArray[indexPath.row]
        cell.lbDescription!.text = self.testdecr[indexPath.row]
        cell.logo!.image = self.imagestored



        return cell
    }

}
```

[image: the error]

Comment: A `PFImageView` is a UI object that downloads and displays images, you are already downloading the image "manually", so you don't need to use a `PFImageView`, just set the image variable to the `UIImage`.

Comment: That works, but the images are not displaying. http://postimg.org/image/uvg90z2sz/ @EmilioPelaez

Comment: Did you try calling `self.tableView.reloadData()` inside, perhaps at the very end of, the `if error == nil` statements, just before the `else {` line?

Comment: No still not displaying the image

Comment: it doesn't work when you put `self.tableView.reloadData()` right after the closure of your `for-loop`?

Comment: No still not displaying any images

Answer (score 0):

In your code you never initialize imagestored (PFImageView) but only image (UIImage). try to change in to

```
cell.logo!.image = self.image
```

I no have idea if PFImageView has any

```
PFImageView.image
```

instances, than should be UIImage() class.

Also you should have something like this:

```
 if let userImageFile = object["imagefile"] as? PFFile {
                     userImageFile.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock {
                        (imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                        if error == nil {
                            if let imageData = imageData {
                                 self.image = UIImage(data:imageData)!

                                 var img = UIImage(data:imageData)
                                 image.append(img)
                                 self.tableView.reloadData()
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: Yeah I've changed it to UIImage but it's still not displaying any images

Comment: if you change your code with cell.logo!.image = self.image, maybe you no have any pictures on server!? After self.image = UIImage(data:imageData)! you should add tableView.reloadData()

Comment: Yeah that's working now! Thanks But it's only displaying one image! for all of them. Is this because I'm storing it in a UIImage? It seems that it's only taking one image from Parse http://postimg.org/image/uvg90z2sz/

Comment: Yes, this is easy to solve. The most fast way (but it is a little bit dirty) create just array of UImages `image = [UIImage]()`, so when you going to query just go for `self.image.append(UIImage(data:imageData)!)` and here we go.

Comment: When I do that I get a breakpoint when I'm setting the cell . http://postimg.org/image/6rgw9acut/

Comment: If you no have `self.tableView.reloadData()` "only" after `self.image.append(UIImage(data:imageData)!)`, that can be possible.

Comment: Ok, every row on your database is with the image data? If not create an var a part for parsed image like var `img = UIImage()` ( create it in the parsing script ), than `img = UIImage(data:imageData)` and then `image.append(img)`. That should work.

Comment: Like this? http://postimg.org/image/44qsl6lth/  Because that's still giving a breakpoint

Comment: It is normal than error persist, i was meaning just before `img = UIImage(data.imageData)`, i will edit it in my code check it

Comment: What before img = UIImage(data.imageData)?

Answer (score -1):

Try to set the image to UIImage and call do_table_refresh() at the next line

Comment: Which line? The one after the setting image stored? because that doesn't display the image